# Overwrite text in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i want to overwrite the text in the text file with a new text but when I use WriteLine or File.WriteAllLines in c#, it deletes the existing text and writes a new one instead.

```
private void Key_Press(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\my\Desktop\test.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.E)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(@"C:\Users\my\Desktop\test.txt", "E");
    }

    else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(@"C:\Users\my\Desktop\test.txt", "A");
        
    }
}
```

In the example here, when I press "E" it writes "E" to the text file, but when I press "A" it deletes "E" and only becomes "A".
It was supposed to be "EA".

Comment: Isn't your problem statement a contradiction?  "i want to overwrite the text in the text file with a new text but when I use WriteLine or File.WriteAllLines in c#, it deletes the existing text and writes a new one instead."  Can that not be paraphrased as "I want to overwrite the text in the text file but when I use `File.WriteAllLines` it overwrites the text"?

Comment: You want to `append` to the file, not `overwrite` it

Comment: Are you trying to _Append_ the text to the text file?  That's do able, but you need to go to the end of the file and then append the character there.  Using `WriteLine` is a bit heavy handed for that.  You need to explain what you want to do better.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to `Append`, not *overwrite* the text:

```
private void Key_Press(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyChar == 'A' || e.KeyChar == 'E')
    File.AppendAllText((@"C:\Users\my\Desktop\test.txt", e.KeyChar.ToString());
}
```